# What are the correct attributes for runFormPost in POST handler?

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I am new to Yesod and Haskell and I do not understand how should I treat the runFormPost function when my form takes multiple attributes. I will give an example:

This is my form:

```
orderForm :: [Entity Food] -> Int -> Maybe Order -> Text -> Form Order
orderForm foods price order email = renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ Order
  <$> pure email
  <*> areq (selectFieldList foodList) "Food" (orderFood <$> order)
  <*> pure price
  <*  bootstrapSubmit (BootstrapSubmit ("Send" :: Text) "btn-info" [])
```

When I am rendering it in get handler, I am using it like this:

```
(form, _) <- generateFormPost $ orderForm foods defaultFoodPrice Nothing email
```

Now I want to run the form in post handler and I am not sure if I need to pass the same arguments even though I do not need? is the correct approach to just pass empty values?

```
((res, form), _) <- runFormPost $ orderForm [] 0 Nothing ""
```

If I understand it, the form now gets the value from the input from the user so I do not need to pass it any arguments, it should have everything what it needs, right? 
Thanks for clarification.

Comment: So, it seems that `pure` doesn't create form fields. Instead it seems to use whatever argument you give it in `runFormPost` to create the `Order`. Is your goal to have a text field to enter an email, filling it with a default value of "email" (same question for the price field)? If you could describe what you want your form be like I think I can answer your question.

Comment: They don't apply directly to your question, but since you said you're new, it might be worth checking out the [Yesod book chapter on forms](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms) or the forms portion of [this screencast](http://youtu.be/SadfV-qbVg8?t=12m7s).